# Recipe calls for garlic powder and all I have is garlic salt

Tags: substitutions, garlic

If so what is the proper amount to put in? It calls for 2 tablespoons of garlic powder but I got garlic salt. Anyone?

Comment: The proper amount is to put in as little as necessary to avoid salt overload in your food.

Answer (score 3):

Garlic salt is typically 3 parts salt to 1 part garlic powder. It's *mostly* salt.

That means if you use 3x the amount, you'll end up with roughly the same amount of garlic powder, but also a *lot* of salt.

Are you able to reduce salt elsewhere in the recipe? If not, I would just leave it out. Generally you can substitute garlic powder for garlic salt (just add salt) but not the other way around.

Comment: I left the salt out of it and only used half the amount of the garlic salt. Guess we will see how it turns out.

Comment: Or use 1.25 times the amount of salt required as garlic salt to get some of the benefit of the garlic flavor.  This will leave the original amount of salt.  -- Note:  started typing this before the above comment was entered.

Comment: If desperate, you could exploit the fact that salt is water soluble, while garlic powder is not. Put the desired amount of garlic salt on a paper towel (or filter paper), cup the paper, and pour some water through it to dissolve the salt. What's left will be wet garlic powder.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Expensive wet salty garlic powder :-)

Comment: Certainly an interesting method, @WayfaringStranger, but I don't think I've ever been *that* desperate for garlic powder. :)

Comment: Although I find that rehydrating garlic powder actually improves its performance considerably... so....